# Are there any issues with using block for an IDisposable within a try catch block?

Tags: c#, .net

The [MSDN recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) putting any instantiation of classes that implement `IDisposable` into a `using` block. Or alternatively, if it is being instantiated within a `try-catch` block, then `Dispose` in `Finally`.

Are there any problems with using a `using` block within a `try-catch` block like so?

```
try
{
    using (Foo bar = new Foo())
    {
       bar.doStuff();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //vomit e
}
```

Of course I can just call `Dispose` in a `Finally` block, but I'm a newbie to programming and I'm just curious to know if doing something like this is practically acceptable or if someone would smack me up the back of my head and yell at me that I'm `Doing-It-Wrong™`.

Or rather, I'm more interested in knowing why this would be wrong if it is.

Comment: No, this is fine. Why would it be wrong? Although I would personally use the try-catch-finally in this case, seeing as there's already a `try` block (in the general case this may actually matter if you need to use `bar` in the `catch`, but you don't in your example).

Comment: Your using statement will dispose of the object, and your try catch will handle any errors. How you are doing it above is absolutely fine

Comment: This is a good idea because it promotes consistency with regards to disposal. Just always use using if you can. Simple rule, almost always a good guideline.

Comment: A newbie who refers to MSDN and asks sensible questions. I'm liking you already!

Comment: But then you don't have access to bar in the Exception.  So you have no access to the object that threw the exception.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, that looks perfectly fine. Your bar instance will be disposed before you even get into the catch block.

Comment: Aha, the bar instance will be disposed before it even gets to the catch block. That is what I didn't realize and why I asked. And as others have also pointed out that makes it problematic if you wanted to use bar for something during catch. Thanks everyone for the answers :)

Answer (score 6):

This is... *drum roll*... absolutely fine.

The only issue is that you shouldn't use `catch (Exception)`, but catch the specific errors you're interested in (even if this is just an example), but that has no bearing on the `using`. In fact, the only reason why you would put the `using` outside the `try` block is because you want to continue doing something with `bar` that's unrelated to the code that failed -- otherwise, keeping the scope as small as possible is generally a good idea.

Comment: @Aron unless you specifically want the stack trace from the error handler - to I indicate error handling failed, that is.

Comment: @Aron: Rethrowing messes up the stack trace a little too, IIRC.  (The damage is limited to the current frame, but instead of the line that called the code that caused the error, you instead see the rethrow point.)  If you can't recover, and don't have to clean up, don't catch.

Answer (score 4):

It is OK but you lost access to object that would have caused the exception in the exception.
And catching general exceptions is not considered a good practice

```
Foo bar = null;
try
{
    bar = new Foo();
    bar.doStuff();
}
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
{
    //vomit e
    Debug.WriteLine(e.msg);
    if(bar == null) 
       Debug.WriteLine("bar = new Foo() failed ");
    else 
       Debug.WriteLine("bar fail ID = " + bar.ID);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // ...
    // unless you are going to handle it gracefully you should rethrow it
}
finally 
{
    if(bar != null) bar.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: @JeroenMostert Added the null and bar.doStuff could fail.

Comment: This works, but the multiple `null` checks are awkward -- and I find it difficult to imagine a real scenario where you want to handle an error both from constructing a `Foo` and calling a method on it in the same block. The outer block is almost *but not entirely* what `using` does, so I'd be tempted to rewrite it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert If you would rather have two catch blocks than two checks for null then is go for it.  I can't imagine a single scenario in which I would rather have two catch.

Answer (score 1):

Your example code is redundant.  The [`Using()` documentation states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664736%28VS.71%29.aspx):

A using statement of the form

```
using (ResourceType resource = expression)
```

statement corresponds to one of two possible expansions. When ResourceType is a value type, the expansion is

```
{
   ResourceType resource = expression;
   try {
      statement;
   }
   finally {
      ((IDisposable)resource).Dispose();
   }
}
```

Otherwise, when ResourceType is a reference type, the expansion is

```
{
   ResourceType resource = expression;
   try {
      statement;
   }
   finally {
      if (resource != null) ((IDisposable)resource).Dispose();
   }
}
```

In either expansion, the resource variable is read-only in the embedded statement.

Your code will ultimately look something like:

```
try
{
    Foo bar = new Foo()
    try
    {
       bar.doStuff();
    }
    finally 
    {
       if (bar != null) ((IDisposable)bar).Dispose();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //vomit e
}
```

No real reason for two try statements.  It's not *wrong* code, it's just redundant in the context of multiple try statements.  You question appears to be about `Disposing` of an object.  In this context, it is redundant.  If you are also concerned about the object constructor throwing an exception, the obviously this would be needed.

> Are there any problems with using a using block within a try-catch block like so?

No, I write your example all the time.

> Of course I can just call Dispose in a Finally block,

Sort of, the constructor must be called outside the try/catch, otherwise the variable will be out of scope by the time you reach the finally block

valid:

```
var foo = new bar();
try
{
}
finally
{
  foo.Dispose();
}
```

invalid:

```
try
{
  var foo = new bar();
}
finally
{
  foo.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: What's redundant? Your code snippets do not catch anything.

Comment: Why does that make the OP's code redundant? Where *exactly* do you see the redundancy? (It's possible that the question has changed since you posted your answer, of course, but if so you should amend your answer too.)

Comment: this simply explains how using works, it doesnt say anything about whether or not using using inside a try catch is good, bad, redundant or anything. I would argue that using using inside try catch is very good since this allows the reader to see the correct common use idiom

Comment: @JonSkeet, Isn't this effectively try { try { dostuff } finally { } } catch { } and is the outer try not redundant? Not a rhetorical question.

Comment: It's redundant in terms of the question regarding *Disposing of objects*.  However, it is very good practice to also throw an additional try/catch around the constructor if one believe it could throw an exception (*which is not at all what the OP is trying to understand IMHO*).

Comment: @StephenKennedy: Yes, it's try/try/finally/catch... but it's not redundant as without the try/catch you can't have a catch. It could be converted into a try/catch/finally, but there's no part of the existing code which is redundant, in that there's nothing you can remove from it without changing the behaviour. If you remove the try/catch, it no longer catches. If you remove the using statement, it no longer disposes.

Comment: The code doesn't contain two `try` blocks. That, on the IL level, this is expanded to two `try` blocks seems irrelevant. The obvious alternative using a single `try` block is not semantically equivalent. It would be a bad idea to "write out" the `using` statement so as to avoid "redundancy", since the code would no longer clearly express its intentions.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is fine, but if you want to access `bar` during the `catch`, you'll need an inner `try catch`:

```
try
{
    using (Foo bar = new Foo())
    {
      try
      {
        bar.doStuff();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        //vomit e, with bar available.
      }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //vomit e, relating to a problem during creation of Foo.
}
```

or, as suggested in the comments, factor out the inner block into a new method.

Comment: If you *are* going that route, you probably want to factor out the inner block to a new method, because nested `try` \ `catch` blocks are pretty hard to read (even more so than nested other things, I mean).